# Why is the bottom margin of the <p> element overlapping with the top margin of the <label> element?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following HTML and CSS codes in Visual Studio Code as shown in the following code snippet, and examined the output in an HTML web page. When I inspected each individual element on the page, I found that the `<p>` element had a margin of "16px 0px" despite the fact that I didn't configure any margin for the `<p>` element. Does a `<p>` element have a default margin?

I also found that the top margin of the first `<label>` element (which was 16px) overlapped with the bottom margin of the `<p>` element (which was also 16px). Could you please explain why the two margins overlap?

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

select:focus {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>:focus CSS Pseudo-class</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/focus_pseudo-class.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>Which flavor would you like to order?</p>
    <label>Full Name: <input name="firstName" type="text"></label>
    <label>Flavor:
            <select name="flavor">
                <option>Cherry</option>
                <option>Green Tea</option>
                <option>Moose Tracks</option>
                <option>Mint Chip</option>
            </select>
        </label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it call margin collapsing. here is a link for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because they take default styling. To overcome the default styling use the *universal selector* **ref**: [Univerasal Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). To set them styling to zero add this below styling in CSS file...

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

This will set margin and padding to zero for all element using default styling. If you want to explore more... **visit** : [Specificity](https://web.dev/learn/css/specificity)  for CSS.